# bash case && extra OPTARG

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I ran into an interesting scenario last night and, so far, my google foo has been unable to find a work around.  I have a script that supports a number of arguments.  A user (damn those users) didn't specify an argument for an option and the results were ... unexpected.

The code:

```
while getopts "a:c:d:De:rs:" arg
do
  case ${arg} in
    a)  app=${OPTARG} ;;
    c)  cmd=${OPTARG} ;;
    d)  domain=${OPTARG} ;;
    D)  Debug=1 ;;
    e)  env=${OPTARG} ;;
    r)  Doit=1 ;;
    s)  subapp=${OPTARG} ;;
    *)  echo "You are DISCREPANT!!";;
    # *)  usage "Invalid argument ${arg}::${OPTARG}" ;;
  esac
done

if [ ${Debug} -gt 0 ]
then
  echo "Env:    ${env}"
  echo "App:    ${app}"
  echo "Subapp: ${subapp}"
  echo "Cmd:    ${cmd}"
  echo "Doit:   ${Doit}"
  echo "Debug:  ${Debug}"
  exit 1
fi
```

Specifying all the args correctly results in:

```
$ ./mwctl -a weblogic -c start -s admin -e trn -r -D
Env:    trn
App:    weblogic
Subapp: admin
Cmd:    start
Doit:   1
Debug:  1
```

Forgetting the '-s' results in:

```
$ ./mwctl -D -a weblogic -c start admin -e trn -r
Env:
App:    weblogic
Subapp:
Cmd:    start
Doit:   0
Debug:  1
```

Similar results for skipping other args with options.  It seems that 'case' loses its mind when presented with an OPTARG that doesn't have an OPT...

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to catch this.

Comment: The parsing of the command line stops when a non-option is found. That's why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `getopt` instead of `getopts`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OPT=$(getopt \
    --options a:c:d:De:rs: \
    --name "$0" \
    -- "$@"
)

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo You are doing it wrong!
    exit 1
fi

eval set -- "${OPT}"

while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -a)  app=${2}; shift 2;;
        -c)  cmd=${2}; shift 2;;
        -d)  domain=${2}; shift 2;;
        -D)  Debug=1; shift;;
        -e)  env=${2}; shift 2;;
        -r)  Doit=1; shift;;
        -s)  subapp=${2}; shift 2;;
        --)  break;;
    esac
done

echo "Env:    ${env}"
echo "App:    ${app}"
echo "Subapp: ${subapp}"
echo "Cmd:    ${cmd}"
echo "Doit:   ${Doit}"
echo "Debug:  ${Debug}"

$ ./mwctl -a weblogic -c start -s admin -e trn -r -D
> Env:    trn
> App:    weblogic
> Subapp: admin
> Cmd:    start
> Doit:   1
> Debug:  1

$ ./mwctl -D -a weblogic -c start admin -e trn -r   
> Env:    trn
> App:    weblogic
> Subapp: 
> Cmd:    start
> Doit:   1
> Debug:  1
```

Note that when you are googling `getopts` vs. `getopt`, you will find many people complaining about `getopt`. As far as I can tell, this is always about an older version of `getopt`, which indeed was very buggy. My experience is, that `getopt` has more options and is also more robust than `getopts`.

To check if you have the enhanced `getopt` version, you can run

```
getopt -T
echo $?
```

If the output is `4`, you have the enhanced version.

Comment: Well, that does a lot better job of catching invalid arguments.  Thanks alot!  I appreciate the help.

Doug

Comment: why not put the `shift 2` as the last statement in the `while true` instead of putting it after almost every case in the `case`?

Comment: If you have a situation in which *every* arg has an option, then 'shift 2' after the case would work.  in this scenario, though, at least two of the options dont' take args.

Answer (score 4):

The traditional Unix convention is that a command line has options (including arguments of options), *then* non-option arguments of the command. In `mwctl -D -a weblogic -c start admin -e trn -r`, the options are `-D` (no argument), `-a` (argument: `weblogic`), and `-c` (argument: `start`). The next word is `admin`, which isn't an option, so the options are over. The non-option arguments are therefore `admin`, `-e`, `trn` and `-r`. The `getopt` builtin implements this convention.

The GNU convention is that an argument that begins with `-` *anywhere on the command line* is an option, unless there is a `--` argument before it, with the caveat that arguments of options don't count. Under the GNU convention, in `mwctl -D -a weblogic -c start admin -e trn -r`, there is an option `-D`, an option `-a` with the argument `weblogic`, an option `-c` with the argument `start`, a non-option argument `admin`, an option `-e` with the argument `trn` and an option `-r`.

`case` doesn't “lose its mind”, your problem has nothing to do with `case`. Your code is missing the extraction of non-option arguments:

```
case $arg in …
esac
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
echo "There are $# non-option arguments, the first is $1"
```

If the command doesn't support any non-option arguments, you need to state this explicitly.

```
…
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
  echo >&2 "Extraneous argument: $1"
  exit 3
fi
```